# Child process not terminating when main process ends

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I create a process using [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw).  This process has a GUI (not a console application), so I execute [WaitForInputIdle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-waitforinputidle) after the process is created. I see the window pop up, so I'm quite sure this part works.

When I then terminate the main process (CTRL+C), the child process that was created keeps existing. Am I missing an option somewhere? Is this normal behaviour? I would like all the children processes to terminate as soon as the main one exits.

Comment: this is normal behavior

Comment: Why do you assume the child process should exit once the process that launches it exits?

Comment: the polite way is to have an IPC channel into the child processes and ask them to politely self-terminate or send them a terminate signal. I don't know GUIs worth beans, but  `PROCESS_INFORMATION` you can get from the `CreateProcessW` call holds information you need to [attach to a console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole) and [force-feed it a break event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/generateconsolectrlevent) or be even more forceful.

Comment: @user4581301 USually best to have the child monitor the parent and if the parent dies exit the process otherwise if the main process crashes or is force terminated via the task manager the child may never know.

Comment: suppose you start word or excel from the cimmand line  - do you expect them to close if you shut down the command line shell?

Comment: Just to back-up Jasper: I can understand the expectation that child processes may be terminated with its parent process. Isn't it how its usual in *ix OSes? Even in Windows, when I close the git bash it tears down all the `git gui`-s and `gitk`-s I started in it before. (I never was aware that it's that complicated to achieve this effect on Windows.) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I then terminate the main process (CTRL+C), the child process that was created keeps existing.

This is normal behavior.

> Am I missing an option somewhere?

No.

> Is this normal behaviour?

Yes.

> I would like all the children processes to terminate as soon as the main one exits.

The best option would be to have the parent communicate with its children.  If the parent is told to exit gracefully, it can notify its children to exit before it then exits.  If the children lose communication with their parent, they can just exit themselves.

If that is not an option, then consider adding the parent and children to a [Job Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects), and then terminate the Job.

Comment: Thanks!
In my case, I have no control over the child process, (e.g. like spawning a notepad.exe instance). Is it in this case possible to communicate to that process to tell it to exit? Or am I supposed to always use a Job Object then?

Comment: @Jasper Notepad has no concept of a parent, so it can't monitor the parent. But the parent can still close Notepad gracefully, ie by sending it WM_CLOSE/WM_QUIT, etc. But if the parent dies unexpectedly, Notepad won't know. So, hence Jobs.